# Catching low level express js exceptions

Tags: node.js, express

When I stress test my Express server (bombarding it with requests), I can crash it with the following error:

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: accept EMFILE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at TCP.onconnection (net.js:1308:24)
```

Under load, I want Express to ignore TCP requests it cannot handle and move on, not crash. How can I cleanly catch `accept EMFILE` errors?

(Note: I have setup [toobusy-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/toobusy-js%60) but can still trigger the error.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define error-handling middleware like other middleware, except with four arguments instead of three, specifically with the signature (err, req, res, next). For example:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});
```

You define error-handling middleware last, after other app.use() and routes calls; for example:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');

app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // logic
});
```

http://expressjs.com/guide/error-handling.html

If that doesn't work you can use `process.on('uncaughtException'`.  Or you can use `pm2` to autorestart your app.

Comment: That's how it works.  See link.  Text is from Express docs.  You can ask Express devs.

Comment: The Express error handler middleware does not work. It doesn't catch this exception.

Comment: See the rest of my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure `process.on('uncaughtException')` is safe and clean.

Comment: You can look for just that exception type.  Or if you don't want to do that, again, see the rest of my answer -- pm2 is standard.  Also putting nginx in front is standard and that might help depending on nginx config.